# In VB.Net, does the use of statically-defined constants, as opposed to equivalent string literals, increase efficiency?

Tags: vb.net, string, performance, constants

Let's say you have 10 different spots in a class where the string "Abc123" is hard-coded.  I know it's a good idea to replace all those with a constant anyway; what I'm wondering about though is if doing that speeds up execution of the program any.  I heard somewhere a while back that it does so in AS3, although I'm not really even sure about that.

Plus if replacing equivalent string literals with statically-defined constants increases performance, by how much?  Is this going to be about the same in most procedural / object-oriented languages?  But I'm mostly just wondering if it does increase the performance at all.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by AS3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes no difference.  The compiler already gathers identical string literals with the same value and turns them into a single object.  It is a very common compiler optimization called "string interning" and is simple to implement with a dictionary, the vb.net compiler implements it as well.

You can see this for yourself by looking at your assembly with ildasm.exe.  Use View + Show Token Values so you can see the string numbers.  For example, this code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim s1 = "hello"
    Dim s2 = "hello"
End Sub
```

generates:

```
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "hello" /* 70000001 */
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldstr      "hello" /* 70000001 */
  IL_000c:  stloc.1
```

Note how the token values, 70000001, are the same.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I'll have to check out that executable you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Hans Passant. But I just want to add that using constants would make your code much more easier to maintain in the future.